# Define foreign key in Postgres to a subset of a target table

Tags: sql, postgresql, subtyping

Example:
I have:

```
Table A:  
 int id  
 int table_b_id

Table B:  
 int id  
 text type
```

I want to add a constraint check on column table_b_id that will verify that it points only to rows in table B which their type value is 'X'.
I can't change table structure.
I've understood it can be done with 'CHECK' and a postgres functions which will do the specific query but I've saw people recommending to avoid it.
Any inputs on what is the best approach to implement it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is not a `FOREIGN KEY`, which, in PostgreSQL, refers to a (number of) column(s) in an other table where there is a unique index on that/those column(s), and which may have associated automatic actions when the value(s) of that/those column(s) change (`ON UPDATE`, `ON DELETE`).

You are trying to enforce a specific kind of referential integrity, similar to what a `FOREIGN KEY` does. You can do this with a `CHECK` clause and a function (because the `CHECK` clause does not allow sub-queries), you can also do it with [table inheritance and range partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) (refer to a child table which holds only rows where `type = 'X'`), but it is probably the easiest to do this with a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trf_test_type_x() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM * FROM tableB WHERE id = NEW.table_b_id AND type = 'X';
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    -- RAISE NOTICE 'Foreign key violation...';
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE tr_test_type_x
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_test_type_x();
```

You can create a partial index on `tableB` to speed things up:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_type_X ON tableB(id) WHERE type = 'X';
```

Comment: Can I define a sub-table with inheritance which include only part of the original table rows?

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution, in my opinion, is to use [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html) to get a subtyping behavior:

[**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup with inheritance**:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12581/3)

```
create table B ( id int primary key );

-- Instead to create a 'type' field, inherit from B for
-- each type with custom properties:
create table B_X ( -- some_data varchar(10 ),
                   constraint pk primary key (id)
                 ) inherits (B);

-- Sample data:
insert into B_X (id) values ( 1 );
insert into B (id)   values ( 2 );

-- Now, instead to reference B, you should reference B_X:
create table A ( id int primary key, B_id int references B_X(id) );

-- Here it is:
insert into A values ( 1, 1 );

--Inserting wrong values will causes violation:
insert into A values ( 2, 2 );
```

> ERROR: insert or update on table "a" violates foreign key constraint "a_b_id_fkey"
>    Detail: Key (b_id)=(2) is not present in table "b_x".

**Retrieving all data from base table**:

```
select * from B
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12581/3/0)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  2 |
|  1 |
```

**Retrieving data with type**:

```
SELECT p.relname, c.*
FROM B c inner join pg_class p on c.tableoid = p.oid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12581/3/1)**:

```
| relname | id |
|---------|----|
|       b |  2 |
|     b_x |  1 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the educating solution, but since I can't change the database schema it wouldn't solve my current problem. It will definitely be useful in future scenarios.